How can I resolve the "spawn ENOENT" error when running a Sencha CMD command in a Termux environment on an Android device?
Hello everyone I need help when I started learning extjs framework, I got an error. When I run the "start" command the error message appears like this: [ERR] [ERR] Error: spawn /data/data/com.termux/files/home/npm/modern-app/node_modules/@sencha/cmd/dist/sencha ENOENT at ChildProcess._handle. onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19) at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) does anyone know the solution I should do? Thank you.
I hope that the packages that have been created through extjs can be developed properly and the applications created can appear in the browser.
